# How to reverse BeautifulSoup.find_all()?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How do I reverse the order of BeautifulSoup's find_all? (I'd like to remove empty p-tags from the end and stop when non-empty.)

```
soupcleanup = BeautifulSoup ( contentsinputphp, 'html5lib' )
for element in soupcleanup.find_all ():
    print ( "###", element, "###" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the order of found tags (e.g with `[::-1]`) and `break` on first non-empty tag:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<p>not empty</p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p></p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


for p in soup.select("p")[::-1]:
    if p.text.strip() == "":
        p.extract()
    else:
        break

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<p>not empty</p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p></p>
<p>not empty</p>
```